# How to random between TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: mysql, random, boolean

As the question states, I need to insert a random value, one of either 0 or 1; how do I use the RAND() function properly to achieve this?

Comment: With results being `true`, `false`, and....  `maybe`?

Comment: @Moo-Juice Just `TRUE` or `FALSE`, nothing in between. Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote the question.  I just thought the wording of "random between TRUE and FALSE" was funny. :)

Answer (score 12):

use the modulo operator

```
select floor(rand() * 10) % 2
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27153)

Answer (score 4):

RAND() returns a random number between 0 and 1, so you can just round the floating precision to the nearest whole integer...effectively 0 or 1:

```
SELECT ROUND(RAND())
```

This is working great for me.

Answer (score 0):

select case when RAND() > 0.5 then 1 else 0 end